# PayPal sandbox test accounts - inconsistent results

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

While testing payments in the sandbox using SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment, testing works as expected.

Payments are reflected in the developer portal and in the test account. The developer account and test accounts are more than 3 years old.

However, when using a new test account created in the last 30 days, the same test fails without error and are payments are not reflected in the test account or in the developer portal.

I suspect that there may be some difference between the older test accounts and the new. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you testing deprecated NVP APIs that are several generations old, instead of [REST v2/checkout/orders](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/) (with or without a [modern UI for approval](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)) ?

---

It's hard to say what specifically the problem might be since you don't share any API responses, but at a guess the email address of the sandbox receiver account is not confirmed.

Check in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email , resend confirmation message as needed

Read confirmation messages in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F , and log in again to confirm

If that's not the issue, you'll need to share API responses.

Comment: "First of all" - Simple. That is the requirement.  
Orders API is also being used without issue.
The API responses are positive with no errors. Sandbox accounts do not match the API responses. That's the thing. I believe it's an inconsistency with legacy sandbox accounts that likely isn't worth the effort.

Comment: All I can say is that if you don't log and share the "positive with no errors" API responses with all details, no one can be of more specific help